# JavaScript: invoke function or call a property via reflection

Tags: javascript, reflection

Is there a way to call a function (or a property) on an object via reflection, in JavaScript?

Lets say that during run-time, my code has already determined that objectFoo indeed has a property called 'bar'.   Now that my code knows that, the next thing I want to do is invoke that.   Normally i would do this:  var x = objectFoo.bar.    But 'bar' was determined at run time, so I need to invoke it using reflection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EVAL:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Eval will allow you to run any javascript code by passing in a string and having the javascript engine evaluate it as javascript code.

If you mean that you want to first search a list properties of an object, then look at this:

```
var o = {}
for(att in o){
    alert(o[att]);
}
```

If you do this, you can even set the property's value by accessing it as if it were an array (all objects are actually associative arrays).

```
obj["propertyName"] = "new value";
obj["MethodName"]();
```

Comment: omg of course... eval.  I'm an idiot.  thank you, i should have thought of that.

Comment: eval() is a much bigger stick than you need to do what you want.  Simply use associative array syntax: `var propName = 'bar'; var x = objectFoo[propName];`

Comment: Related note, if the scope of the variable containing the function is "window", you can use parent[var]();

Answer (score 7):

In JavaScript, object methods are really just properties containing functions.  Like all properties, you can refer to them using associative array syntax:

```
var x = { 'a': 1 };
x.a += 1;
x['a'] += 1;
console.log(x.a);
```

Output is: `3`.

So if you have the name of a method you want to invoke on `myObject`:

```
var methodName = 'myMethod';

// Invoke the value of the 'myMethod' property of myObject as a function.
myObject[methodName]();
```

Comment: My answer had this in it... It had this AND Eval.

Answer (score 4):

Create object (invoke constructor) via reflection:

```
SomeClass = function(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log('Your reflection');
}

ReflectUtil.newInstance('SomeClass', 5, 7);
```

and implementation:

```
var ReflectUtil = {};

/**
 * @param strClass:
 *          class name
 * @param optionals:
 *          constructor arguments
 */
ReflectUtil.newInstance = function(strClass) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    var clsClass = eval(strClass);
    function F() {
        return clsClass.apply(this, args);
    }
    F.prototype = clsClass.prototype;
    return new F();
};
```

Comment: Love the concept.. One confusion. How to get output of a function?

Comment: Activate the browser console with F12, and select "Console" in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Create a register object:

```
var funcRegister = {};
```

Create a function to call the other:

```
var callReflectionFunc = function(type, obj) {
    var func = false;
    if(funcRegister[type])
        func = funcRegister[type](obj);

    return func;
}
```

Populate your register with functions:

```
funcRegister['yourtype1'] = function(obj) {
    console.log('your type 2');

    return obj;
}

funcRegister['yourtype2'] = function(obj) {
    console.log('your type 2');

    return obj;
}
```

Then call it with your type and an object where you can put your args

```
callReflectionFunc(type, obj);
```